# why should I call super when there is no code

Tags: android, lint

when i looked into AppCompatActivity.java to study APIs
i found that onSupportActionModeStarted() requires overriding method to call the super.method().even if there is no code. do you have any clue on it?

```
/**
 * Notifies the Activity that a support action mode has been started.
 * Activity subclasses overriding this method should call the superclass implementation.
 *
 * @param mode The new action mode.
 */
@Override
@CallSuper
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(@NonNull ActionMode mode) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Today*, there is nothing in `onSupportActionModeStarted()` in `AppCompatActivity`. By adding `@CallSuper`, Google is saying "in the future, we might put code here, so please call through to the superclass implementation, so that your app does not break in the future".

Comment: Implementing AppCompatCallback in a subClass makes clear of the intent of the class  and it is easy to see where the overridden methods belong, so I was wondering why the AppCompatActivity implements it. From the opinion of the respondents, you may think that the developer is likely to use AppCompatCallback on the next platform, so that no complicated work is required. But it also hurts the clarity of the class. In the end, the continuity of the business is more important than the clarity of the code.